# Converting DataSet/DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Please let me know, if there any way to generate CSV files from a DataTable or DataSet? To be specific, without manually iterating through rows of DataTable and concatenating.

Please help

Comment: why do u not want to iterate through the rows of DataTable? That would be quite straight forward...

Comment: I was looking for a more shortcut approach.

Comment: You can check this https://gist.github.com/riyadparvez/4467668

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways to do that.

One of the simplest (IMO) is using [`FileHelpers Library`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)

```
FileHelpers.CsvEngine.DataTableToCsv(dataTable, filename);
```

Answer (score 7):

A relative simple, compact and quite flexible solution could be the following extension method:

```
public static string ToCsv(this DataTable table, string colSep = "", string rowSep = "\r\n")
{
    var format = string.Join(colSep, Enumerable.Range(0, table.Columns.Count)
                                            .Select(i => string.Format("{{{0}}}", i)));

    return string.Join(rowSep, table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                        .Select(i => string.Format(format, i.ItemArray)));
}
```

Please note that this solution could cause problems with huge amounts of data, in which case you should stream the output. Quoting and formatting would of course make the code more complex.

Answer (score 2):

There is, I hope, also a possible way for doing that:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1["Id"] = 1;
        dr1["Name"] = "John Smith";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
        dr2["Id"] = 2;
        dr2["Name"] = "John West";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

        List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        var strlist = from dr in list
                      select dr[0] + ", " + dr[1];
        var csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,strlist);
        Console.WriteLine(csv);
    }
```

Comment: The only drawback I came to notice with this was, we need to concat dt[Index], if more columns are going to be added in future, except for that this looks good.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Dataset To Xls
ExportDataSetToCsvFile(DS,@"C:\\");

internal static void ExportDataSetToCsvFile(DataSet _DataSet, string DestinationCsvDirectory)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataTable DDT in _DataSet.Tables)
        {
            String MyFile = @DestinationCsvDirectory + "\\_" + DDT.TableName.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhMMssffff") + ".csv";//+ DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhMMssffff")
            using (var outputFile = File.CreateText(MyFile))
            {
                String CsvText = string.Empty;

                foreach (DataColumn DC in DDT.Columns)
                {
                    if (CsvText != "")
                        CsvText = CsvText + "," + DC.ColumnName.ToString();
                    else
                        CsvText = DC.ColumnName.ToString();
                }
                outputFile.WriteLine(CsvText.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
                CsvText = string.Empty;

                foreach (DataRow DDR in DDT.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn DCC in DDT.Columns)
                    {
                        if (CsvText != "")
                            CsvText = CsvText + "," + DDR[DCC.ColumnName.ToString()].ToString();
                        else
                            CsvText = DDR[DCC.ColumnName.ToString()].ToString();
                    }
                    outputFile.WriteLine(CsvText.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
                    CsvText = string.Empty;
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }  
}
```

Comment: This answer isnt clear as to how it resolves the OP's question. You should edit this to make it clearer and more readable

Answer (score 1):

So this is a fairly bizarre solution, but it works faster than most as it makes use of the JSON.net library's serialization. This speeds the solution up significantly.

Steps:

1. Create array of every column name in the data table, should be
   simple
2. Use JSON.net to convert datatable to a json string

   `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);`
3. Begin making use of the Replace function on c# strings and strip the
   json string of all json formatting.

   `json = json.Replace("\"", "").Replace("},{", "\n").Replace(":", "").Replace("[{", "").Replace("}]", "");`
4. Then use the array from step 1 to remove all column names from the
   json string. You are left with a csv formatted string.
5. Consider using the array created in step 1 to add the column names
   back in as the first row in csv format.