# Storing a DataTable in a Flatfile

Tags: c#

This is the first time I have done any sort of work with flat files.
I need this to be a plain txt file NOT XML.

I have written the following opting for a comma delimited format.

```
    public static void DataTableToFile(string fileLoc, DataTable dt)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        // get the column headers
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            str.Append(c.ColumnName.ToString() + ",");
        }
        str.Remove(str.Length-1, 1);
        str.AppendLine();
        // write the data here
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var field in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
            }
            str.Remove(str.Length-1, 1);
            str.AppendLine();
        }
        try
        {
            Write(fileLoc, str.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ToDO:Add error logging
        }
    }
```

My question is: Can i do this better or faster?
And `str.Remove(str.Length-1, 1);` is there to remove the last `,` which is the only way I could think of.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You're essentially trying to write a data table to CSV format. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
public static void DataTableToFile(string fileLoc, DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    // get the column headers
    str.Append(String.Join(",", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                      .Select(col => col.ColumnName)) + "\r\n");

    // write the data here
    dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()
           .ForEach(row => str.Append(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray) + "\r\n"));

    try
    {
        Write(fileLoc, str.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ToDO:Add error logging
    }
}
```

Comment: But this writes only the column names, not the data.

Comment: @Tim I believe it is meant to be representative of a *technique*. You would obviously use something very similar on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Exactly MarcGarvll. He wants a faster code not a rent-a-coder.

Answer (score 3):

The key point would be: there is no need to construct this in memory with a `StringBuilder` - you should instead be writing to a file via something like `StreamWriter`, i.e. via `File.CreateText`. The API is similar to `StringBuilder`, but you shouldn't try to *remove* - instead, **don't add** - i.e.

```
bool first = true;
foreach(...blah...) {
    if(first) { first = false; }
    else { writer.Write(','); }
    ... write the data ...
}
```

As another consideration: CSV is **not** just a case of adding commas. You need to think about quoted text (for data with `,` in), and multi-line data. Unless the data is very very simple. You might also want to make the format more explicit than just `.ToString()`, which is very culture-sensitive. The classic example would be large parts of Europe that use `,` as the decimal character, thus "CSV" often uses a different separator, to avoid having to quote everything. If the choice is available, *personally* I'd always use TSV instead of CSV - less problematic (in theory, although you still need to handle data with tabs in).