# Exporting jquery data-table to excel sheet ? MVC4

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

Is there any possible way to export my JQUERY DATA TABLE data to excel sheet ?

Well i tried referring many articles around in Google which tend to suggest  me some plugins so on but i was unable to deal perfectly ! sadly my bad

**My work around** : tried some functionality from articles  which does nothing in my case .

Any workaround  is appreciated and any better links are very helpful too .

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Maybe you can export them to csv. Its much easier

Comment: pardon me mate ! CSV ? is it similar to excel ?

Comment: Depending of the meaning of _similar_. If you only need the data, without formulas, **Yes**. You can open the file with any spreadsheet editor.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4959869/3315914

Comment: awesome :) yes in exact i just need the data which mostly will be text . On my button click i just need the data i filtered to save . your suggestion looks great mate . Then how to do  ? via  plugins ? manually ? confused

Comment: Post some code, it will be easier to help you

Comment: yes thats explains a bit but i guess my scenario little tricky . when i apply searching or something after doing filter when i click save to excel i need just those data to save ? i dont know how to query a jquery DataTable becoz mostly i done plugin stuff ?

Comment: Thats another question.

Comment: well i am offline from my main system but i refered this link to design my JQUERY Data table dynamically from db which works fine .
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part . sorry to bother you .

Comment: yes you are right mate . but if i know how to save i can deal with other stuff . Just looking for starting step .! How to

Comment: Take a look at https://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/ .

Comment: nice one :) will do some workaround and get back to you . Ty for you valuable time