# Write Datatable Content to CSV File in C#.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a data table in C#.Net.Please help me to write Datatable Content to CSV File in Asp.Net(C# language)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it show absolutely no effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();     
var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText("YOURFILE.csv", sb.ToString());
```