# Convert XML file to csv file format in c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv, accord.net

I am using accord.net mouse gesture recognition sample application, which saves the file in above xml format. I need help to convert above xml in to CSV format so i can do machine learning using accord.net Dynamic time warping. I can not figure out how to convert in to csv file.

For example: 261,210,261,214,261,229,261,231

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSequence xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Sequence>
    
    <SourcePath>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>210</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>214</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>227</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>229</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>231</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>234</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>261</X>
        <Y>237</Y>
      </Point>
</Sequence>
</ArrayOfSequence>
```

Comment: Why XML serialization you'r using ?

Comment: i found the source code on accord.net framework website which is using XML Serialization to save file.

Comment: I tried to save as csv but could not.

Comment: Parse XML, write to CSV file. Which part is unclear to you?

Comment: i want to write to CSV.

Comment: Did you search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file

Comment: i only need x and y co-ordinates in my csv file. for example: 261,210,261,214,261,231,261,234

Comment: I have file in xml format, i want to conver that in to csv format. for example: 261,210,261,214,261,231,261,234

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

You can do like this:

```
public class Sequence
{
    public Point[] SourcePath { get; set; }
}

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\youXMLFile.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sequence[]));
    var data=(Sequence[]) serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        List<string> ss = new List<string>();
        foreach (var point in item.SourcePath) ss.Add(point.X + "," + point.Y);
        list.Add(string.Join(",", ss));
    }
    File.WriteAllLines("D:\\csvFile.csv", list);
}
```

Comment: Above code is writing into csv file as {X=261,Y=210},{X=261,Y=214},{X=261,Y=227},{X=261,Y=229}. I need my points as 261,210,261,214,261,227,261,229

Comment: so this is slightly buggy as a general solution, as it doesn't escape commas or quotes.

Comment: @Rob this answer is for specific problem, not for general.

Answer (score 4):

In an alternate way you can use leverage the power of **XSLT** to convert it,

#### Steps

- Create an Xml stylesheet to convert xml to csv
- Use `XslCompiledTransform()` to convert get the csv string
- save the csv string to a file

You may came up with an Xslt like this, call it **data.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Point">
      <xsl:value-of select="X"/>,<xsl:value-of select="Y"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and use the following method

```
public static string ToCSV(string xmlTextDate, string xsltFile)
{
  string result = string.Empty;
  var xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlTextDate);
  var xsltTransform = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
  xsltTransform.Load(xsltFile);

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
      var writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
      using (var rd = new StreamReader(ms))
      {
          var argList = new System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList();
          xsltTransform.Transform(xpathDoc, argList, writer);
          ms.Position = 0;
          result = rd.ReadToEnd();
      }
  }
  return result;
}
```

and call it like this

```
var csvString = ToCSV("yourfile.xml","data.xsl");
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting XML directly into CSV is a little complex task. Instead of this, you can first convert your XML to `DataSet` and then into CSV:

1. Converting XML to Dataset:

   ```cs
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   ds.ReadXml(fileNamePath);
   ```
2. Converting DataTable to CSV.

   Link: [c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv)

Answer (score -12):

Just create a csv file of the XML, Use System.IO and make sure the file is something like

```
fileName = Name + ".csv"
```

Have a read up and look for something like this

```
Path.GetTempPath(), fileName
```

I am a bit sketchy but that should put you on the right track

Comment: i tried but it did not work. i only need x and y co-ordinates in my csv file.

Comment: for example: 261,210,261,214,261,231,261,234

Comment: Im not sure the exact syntax but it should have something to do with that

Comment: This isn't even close to answering the OPs question.

Comment: `filename` will be like `"Name.csv"` and `Path.GetTempPath()` gives _Returns the path of the current user's temporary folder_ that won't transform xml to csv. Consider editing your post else you will keep getting downvoted.