# DataTable to CSV with custom string representation

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I want to convert a DataTable to a CSV string lines, and I want to have the flexibility to code the string representation of each column (Example: I may want Date values in a specific string format, etc.)

I have seen some generic methods to convert a DataTable to CSV here: [c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv)

But none of the methods address custom string representation.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve, can you give few concrete example scenarios please?

Answer (score 1):

Just check the column type and specify the format you want, if it is a date.

```
DataTable dt = ...

// Your custom date format.
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(item =>
        item is DateTime ? ((DateTime)item).ToString(format) : item.ToString()
    )));
}

File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv) as mentioned, I would create an extension method that takes two format strings as parameters and looks like this:

```
    static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToCSV(this DataTable dataTable, string rowFormat, string headFormat)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendFormat(headFormat, columnNames.ToArray<string>());

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat(rowFormat, row.ItemArray);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

Then call it like this:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("value", typeof(double)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dated", typeof(DateTime)));
            dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 1, 2.3, DateTime.Now });
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToCSV("{0}|\"{1}\"|{2:d}", "{0}|{1}|{2}"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

To produce this:

```
id|value|dated
1|"2.3"|04/10/2016
```

This gives you the flexibility to define the structure of your CSV precisely.

If you don't know the structure, then this won't help.