# prepend headers to my csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

I want to prepend headers to my CSV File as to let the data reflect the headings. How would I go about this without having to add it each time writing to the file? Meaning I only want the headers added once on each export. When am exporting to the same file name it should not create duplicates of the same headers. Here is my code below which writes to file:

```
 private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count_row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        int count_cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;

        MessageBox.Show("Please wait while " +comboBox5.Text+ " table is being exported..");
        for (int row_index = 0; row_index <= count_row - 2; row_index++)
        {

            for (int cell_index = 1; cell_index <= count_cell - 1; cell_index++)
            {
                textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[cell_index].Value.ToString() + ",";

            }
            textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + "\r\n";
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Desktop\\"+comboBox5.Text+".csv", textBox8.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Export  of " +comboBox5.Text+ " table is complete!");
        textBox8.Clear();
    }
```

Updated attempt:

```
  private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count_row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        int count_cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;

        MessageBox.Show("Please wait while " + comboBox5.Text + " table is being exported..");

       if (!File.Exists(comboBox5.Text))
        {

            string rxHeader = "Code" + "," + "Description" + "," + "NDC" + "," + "Supplier Code"
               + "," + "Supplier Description" + "," + "Pack Size" + "," + "UOM" + Environment.NewLine;


            for (int row_index = 0; row_index <= count_row - 2; row_index++)
            {

                for (int cell_index = 1; cell_index <= count_cell - 1; cell_index++)
                {
                    textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[cell_index].Value.ToString() + ",";

                }
                textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + "\r\n";
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Desktop\\" + comboBox5.Text + ".csv", textBox8.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Export  of " + comboBox5.Text + " table is complete!");
            textBox8.Clear();
        }

    }
```

I really want to try and achieve it without SteamWriter, where am I going wrong?

```
private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count_row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        int count_cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        string path = "C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Desktop\\" + comboBox5.Text + ".csv";
        string rxHeader = "Code" + "," + "Description" + "," + "NDC" + "," + "Supplier Code"
        + "," + "Supplier Description" + "," + "Pack Size" + "," + "UOM";


        MessageBox.Show("Please wait while " + comboBox5.Text + " table is being exported..");

        for (int row_index = 0; row_index <= count_row - 2; row_index++)
        {

            for (int cell_index = 1; cell_index <= count_cell - 1; cell_index++)
            {
                textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[cell_index].Value.ToString() + ",";

            }
            textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + "\r\n";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, rxHeader);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
            }
            else
            {    
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Export  of " + comboBox5.Text + " table is complete!");
                textBox8.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: MSDN about WriteAllText : _If the target file already exists, it is overwritten._ so the code above always rewrites everything headers or whatelse.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't. I export to file and it appends to the existing data so you are actually wrong with this one. The hidden textbox was the work around for that @Steve

Comment: @RezaAghaei what if I check if it exists as suggested in my updated attempt in my original question

Comment: Steve is not wrong, he actually copy/pasted that straight out of the documentation. WriteAllText overwrites the file. Sure you are working around that by using a string of textboxes to keep the appended text but, in the end, when you call that method, you are replacing the whole file, and not appending to it.

Comment: @blaze_125 yeah am aware of that already. Do you have any suggestions for the above code?

Comment: Obviously you are not that aware of that, otherwise you would not have written this "Actually no it doesn't" in response to Steve's comment. I will likely have something to offer in terms of solution to this question but this had to be pointed out since you're blatantly telling someone is wrong when that person is actually dead right.

Comment: @Jevon first of all, you don't use a TextBox to accumulate your text but at least a StringBuilder that remove the overhead of creating a new string and continuosly replacing the Text property of a TextBox. Second, if you write initially the header then use a boolean global variable in that class that keeps track of this fact and do not repeat the code that creates the header text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer by simply editing my code with this snippet:

```
 if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, rxHeader + textBox8.Text);
    }
    else
    {    
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Export  of " + comboBox5.Text + " table is complete!");
        textBox8.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the short version that will even properly handle values that contain `,` and `"`:

```
dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;  // the row headers column is copied too if visible
dataGridView1.SelectAll();                // only the selected cells are used (the Windows Clipboard is not used)

DataObject dataObject = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();      // 4 Data Formats: Text,Csv,HTML Format,UnicodeText
File.WriteAllText("1.csv", dataObject.GetData("Csv") as string);  // DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue = "Csv"

//string html = Encoding.ASCII.GetString((dataObject.GetData("HTML Format") as MemoryStream).ToArray()); // just the HTML Clipboard Format is in a MemoryStream
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggested solution.
My suggestion is to first check if the file exists or not, to then decide if you need to write the header or not.

```
private void DoTheWork(int fileIDtoUpdate)
    {
        //this is just my representation of what probably already exist in your project
        string textInTheTextBox = "blah blah blah blah\nI love text\nI love code\nI love to Code\ndon't you just love to code!";
        string filePath1 = @"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\40726017\File1.txt";
        string filePath2 = @"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\40726017\File2.txt";
        string filePath3 = @"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\40726017\File3.txt";
        string filePath4 = @"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\40726017\File4.txt";
        string fileToWorkWith = string.Empty;
        //decide which file to work with
        switch (fileIDtoUpdate)
        {
            case 1:
                fileToWorkWith = filePath1;
                break;
            case 2:
                fileToWorkWith = filePath2;
                break;
            case 3:
                fileToWorkWith = filePath3;
                break;
            case 4:
                fileToWorkWith = filePath4;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        //check if the file existed
        bool fileExisted = File.Exists(fileToWorkWith);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileToWorkWith, true))
        {
            if (!fileExisted)
            {
                //if the file did not exist, then you need to put your header line!
                sw.WriteLine("Write your Header Line here");
            }
            sw.WriteLine(textInTheTextBox);//down here... who cares if the file existed or not, you need to append this text to it no matter what!
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really want to do it without SteamWriter, could you take a look at my updated code to see where am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row_index = 0; row_index <= count_row - 2; row_index++)
{
    textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + "\r\n";

    for (int cell_index = 1; cell_index <= count_cell - 1; cell_index++)
    {
        textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[cell_index].Value.ToString() + ",";

    }
}
```

Just go to the property pannel of textBox8. Text and add column header with comma and set the textbox8 visibility to hidden.