# Convert datatable to text not JSON in C#/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

1. I hava records from database in DataTable.
2. I wan't to convert the DataTable into a text.
3. Return the text as string.

Example: Database/DataTable

```
id|name|age
___________
1 |Amy |17
2 |Max |23
3 |aaa |50
......
```

And this my code:

```
string result = MyFunction(MyDataTable);
```

**MyDataTable** is the **DataTable** and **MyFunction** should return this:

```
['id','name',age]
[['1','Amy','17']
['2','Max','23']
['3','aaa','50']]
```

How can I make MyFunction do this?

Comment: that's an array rather than a string, by the looks of it? What's the purpose? What do you want to do with this data?

Comment: I want to load it as text from my server to my program and use it there

Comment: I suggest convert your data table contents to comma separated values (.csv) file and import it to your program. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv

Comment: Mohsin Mehmood  That's work Thanks! I just need time to write my code then post it here

Comment: Best way is to save datatable as Xml using the datatable method WriteXml();

Comment: jdweng that's not what I wan't there info that need name/password and lat's say I need just 1 table not all the database or more than that > where name = 'value' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mohsin Mehmood  I find My answer:

here the code:

```
string MyFunction(DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                      Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine("['" + string.Join("','", columnNames) + "']");

    sb.Append("[");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine("['" + string.Join("','", fields) + "']");
    }
    sb.Append("]");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then:

```
string result = MyFunction(MyDataTable);
```

Result:

```
['id','name',age]
[['1','Amy','17']
['2','Max','23']
['3','aaa','50']]
```