# How can I export to a csv or excel file using a DataGrid (NOT DataGridView) in ASP.NET using VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I'm trying to export data from a DataGrid to a .csv file (or even a .xlsx or .xls file), and can't seem to find an approach that works for my environment (VB.net). Just about everything I've seen online seems to reference a DataGridView, rather than just a plain DataGrid. That, or it will use C# code rather than VB. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I am using Oracle as my database.

For the set up, I have a button on my page that when clicked, I am hoping the code behind will create a .csv file based on the DataGrid. The issue, though, is that I want it to prompt the user to save the file, as opposed to just saving it specifically somewhere. For now, this is the code I have for my button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rpt_fy As String = Session("RPTFY")
    Dim strWHERE As String = " WHERE (FY LIKE '" & rpt_fy & "')"
    Dim strSELECT As String = "SELECT FY, BUDGET, CODE, DEPT, REV FROM DB_PROD"

    OracleSelectCommand1.CommandText = strSELECT & strWHERE

    Dim myDataReader As Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    OracleConnection1.Open()
    myDataReader = OracleSelectCommand1.ExecuteReader

    ' Specify the DataReader as the source of the data for our DataGrid
    ' and then DataBind to display the data in our DataGrid.

    Dim dsConvert As New DataSet()
    dsConvert.Tables.Add("Convert")
    dsConvert.Tables(0).Load(myDataReader)
    DataGrid1.DataSource = dsConvert
    DataGrid1.DataBind()

    ' Close our DataReader and Connection
    myDataReader.Close()
    OracleConnection1.Close()

End Sub
```

For the file, my approach was to use the Response.Write() function to give the user an option to choose where to save the file:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.csv")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

Something I seem to see a lot is is the idea of using HtmlTextWriter to write it, like so:

```
Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter
Dim htmlWrite As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)

Dim strStyle As String = "<style>.text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"
For intTemp As Integer = 0 To DataGrid1.Items.Count - 1
    DataGrid1.Items(intTemp).Cells(0).Attributes.Add("class", "text")
    DataGrid1.Items(intTemp).Cells(1).Attributes.Add("class", "text")
    DataGrid1.Items(intTemp).Cells(3).Attributes.Add("class", "text")
Next

DataGrid1.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
response.Write(strStyle & stringWrite.ToString)
response.End()
```

The problem with this, is that it essentially just writes an html file. I do realize that Excel is supposed to be able to translate the .html file to a .xlsx/.xls file, but our security settings attached to the program no longer make this possible. Hence, I would rather just write it out as a .csv than a html file.

I also saw a few examples of using IO.StreamWriter, but with this we would have to save the file to the server first, which again we cannot do due to security settings.

How can I modify my code to allow me to export from a DataGrid to a .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an existing solution for table to csv. You can get your table out of the DataSet object.

[c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic

        For Each tbl As System.Data.Table In dsConvert.Tables
            Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder
            Dim colNames = tbl.Columns.IEnumerable(Of DataColumn).Select(c >= c.ColumnName)
            sb.Append(String.Join(",", columnNames))
            For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In tbl.Rows
                Dim iEnumFields = row.ItemArray.Select(f >= f.ToString())
                sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", iEnumFields))
            Next
            File.WriteAllText(tbl.TableName & ".csv", sb.ToString())
        Next
```

Comment: This seems really close to what I need, but it's in C#. How would I translate this to VB.NET? I ran the code through this website: https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ but am having issues with IEnumerable and extracting the table from my DataSet object. I added an Imports System.Text for my string builder, but beyond that I'm seeing a lot of red!

Comment: Did you have the imports?
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq

Comment: I have all the imports there, but it says that IEnumerable is not a member of DataColumnCollection. It's also saying that c is not declared. I'll try googling for a bit to see if I can hack something together.