# Is there a way i can write to CSV Faster?

Tags: vb.net

I have a for Loop that grabs data from a data table and writes to a text file, as csv. This works great for small csv files but becomes very very slow when writing bigger csv files, say 5000 records takes 2 minutes. Is there a better way I can do this?

Thanks.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
 dataadapter.Fill(dt)

For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 2

                For j As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    writer.Write(dt.Rows(i).Item(j).ToString().Trim() & ",")

                Next

            Next
```

Comment: Maybe write to the file once instead of for every row and column?  Here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959869/5162073).

Comment: Are you sure that writing to ta file is a bottle neck of the problem?

Comment: No.  But if all else fails you can give it a try.

Comment: You don't show how you obtain the writer - so I am guessing it's a file writer? If so, consider writing to an in-memory stream, then flushing that to a file stream outside of the loop